# How to show the last clicked button?

Tags: flash, button, air, adobe

I use Adobe Animate to build my apps but I don´t know much about AS3.

I have a movie clip which works as a LIST with almost 40 buttons on it. Each button serves to add a movie clip from the library to the stage. After the added movie clip is shown and removed from the stage the user goes back to the LIST and I need a way to let him know which was the last button he clicked on.

Is there a Flash component to do this?

All I need is to show which was the last button clicked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get last button click on button click handler ...please check below code....

var lastButtonClicked:Button;

function onclick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     if(lastButtonClicked != null){
        //This is your last button "lastButtonClicked"
     }
     // Set the last button clicked
     lastButtonClicked = event.currentTarget as Button; 
}
//your button array
var buttonArray:Array = [btn1....btn40];

for(var i:int=0; i<buttonArray.length; i++){
  var btn:Button = buttonArray[i];
  btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onclick);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to hold the last button clicked, and then, on each button click event, register this button to this variable:

```
var lastButtonClicked:Button

function onclick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     // Set the last button clicked
     lastButtonClicked = event.currentTarget as Button; 
}

// Get the last button clicked
var btn:Button = lastButtonClicked;
```